# Using CSS3 box-shadow for a halfway cut-off shadow

Tags: css

What I'm looking to achieve is a "half way" shadow using CSS3 in replacement of an image.

Below is a slightly zoomed example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

There are three elements involved here, as displayed below (scaled down):

[image]

So far I've tried placing a `box-shadow` on element `A` and then pushing a higher `z-index` on element `C` so that the shadow is only visible over element `B`, but couldn't replicate the half-way cut off.

Has anyone attempted to achieve this before, or is the outcome always going to be as 'hacky' as I think it will be?

Comment: You can use `box-shadow: ... inset` for B or I didn't understood you well

Comment: Have you found any solution for this yet? I can give it a try if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting a position on the elements you're applying a z-index to:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vxz9f/

Comment: might want to jog that shadow left a bit so the blur doesn't show on the right: http://jsfiddle.net/Vxz9f/1/

Answer (score 0):

I just faced same problem and fixed it the following way:

- Give the `C` div a higher `z-index`
- Make it overlap (cover/go over) the `A` div for `5px` (or whatever your
  shadow px amount is).

If u do that with the same color, you will hide the shadow perfectly and you'll get your half way shadow.